# Input text jumps a bit in IE11

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

There is a simple example with 2 inputs. One with custom google font and another with default browser font.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kh7KbhdLjjDn6niy8rzt?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" value="jgyq">
    <input type="text" value="jgyq" class="custom-font">
  </body>

</html>

input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.custom-font {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

If you try to select input text and drag to top or bottom, you will notice that input text jumps 1-4px to top or bottom (depend on line-height, height input attributes actually, but jumps always)

Have tried different compinations of padding, line-height, height properties.

I used line-height:1.2; + padding:6px 0; properties to have crossbrowser input (height) in the past. Is there any other good way to set crossbrowser text input withut such jumps and other problems. (IE11+, and modern Chrome, FF, O)

Comment: drag...to where? there's nowhere to drop it? Btw, there's nothing in the script.js, I dunno why you have it in your file.

Comment: Plunker has empty script by default, just push left mouse burton and move your mouse up and down, it happens not always, i was able to reproduce it after 3d drag. If you have open sans font with 1.2 lineheight you will be able to reproduce same thing even in chrome and firefox, lineheight 1.4 solves the problem there. Can't rid of it in ie. Will record a video if noone can reproduce it.